# Navbar Collapse made everything not clickable

Tags: html, css

When I added `position:fixed` to the `navbar-collapse` element, everything on the page that is clickable stop working

```css
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    background: rgba(106, 115, 130, 0.8);
    /* position: fixed; */
    top: 10vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try changing the z-index for the navbar ?

`z-index:1030;`